# Does pygame.display.flip() wait until the hardware executes the command before proceeding to the next line?

Tags: pygame

I'm designing an experiment where I need a very accurate measurement of the interval between flips of the display. I am using pygame.display.flip() followed by time.time() and want to know if the flip function waits for the hardware to execute the command and then proceeds to the next line. If not, is there a way to get the actual display refresh time?

Answer (score 0):

Since pygame is really just SDL in python with more features you can look up SDL_Flip in the SDL docs : http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_Flip

If I understood correctly, it does wait, but only when the game is on fullscreen(since it is then, when double-buffering really occurs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and link. I think the doc states that SDL_Flip (or pygame.display.flip() ) sends the data to the hardware and proceeds to the next line; however, the hardware may still be waiting for the next vertical retrace. In other words, the function call does not wait for the retrace and my time.time() intervals do not include the hardware wait times.